# Windows RDP Black Screen after changing setting in Local Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, group-policy

I often bring my work laptop (Windows 10 Pro) from home and RDP into it from my home desktop (Windows 10 Pro) to use more monitors. However at work the other day I was working on a task and I changed the following setting on my work laptop by performing the following.

1. Go to `Local Group Policy Editor` (Windows icon and type `Edit Group Policy`)
2. Go to `Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Remote Session Environment/`
3. Change `Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions` from Not Configured to Enabled

Since making that change, whenever I try to remote into my work laptop at home from my desktop PC, I get only a black screen. I have ended up changing the setting back to Not Configured instead of enabled, but it did not fix the issue.

I have tried a few different recommendations from what I've found online, but nothing useful yet. (this includes deselecting Persistent bitmap caching and pressing CTRL ALT END).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer in the following [forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remote-desktop-black-screen/63c665b5-883d-45e7-9356-f6135f89837a?page=2) on Micrsoft's website.

The solutions is to go to `Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Remote Session Environment/` and disable `Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections`